# Password must have at least one non-alpha character

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I need a regular expression for a password. The password has to contain at least 8 characters. At least one character must be a number or a special character (not a letter).

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 8)]
[RegularExpression(@"(?=.*\W)?(?=.*\d)", ErrorMessage = "Error message")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

I have a length validation, but I need help with a regular expression that checks if the password contains at least one number or special character.

Examples of valid passwords:

```
testtest85*
testtes*
testtes1
test1234*+
```

Examples of not valid passwords:

```
testtest
testabc
```

Comment: What makes a character special for you?

Comment: What language is that? There may be different regex flavours.

Comment: Why do you use lookahead? Also, lookarounds cannot be optional.

Comment: @Bergi: This looks like C# in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @cashmere - `etc` is not helpful, by `etc` do you mean `; , " ' ? < > { } & ^ % $ # @ ! * . / \ - + = ~ , ` could this list also include non printable characters? What about high order characters that require multiple key strokes to enter (my password generator will create those if asked)?

Comment: Do you know that the password can be all numbers with your rules? `12345678` is a perfect password with your ruleset which is far weaker than anything.

Comment: I assume/believe, by *special character* the OP means any *non-letter character*.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use regex pattern `^(?=.{8})(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])`

---

Explanation:

```
^(?=.{8})(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])
│└──┬───┘└──────┬──────┘
│   │           │
│   │           └ string contains some non-letter character
│   │
│   └ string contains at least 8 characters
│
└ begining of line/string
```

---

If you want to limit also maximum length *(let's say 16)*, then use regex pattern:

```
^(?=.{8,16}$)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: wish I could add more than +1 for explaining the individual parts of it!

Comment: that's some nice ascii art.

Answer (score 2):

Run it through a fairly simple regex: `[^a-zA-Z]`

And then check it's length separately:

```
if(string.Length > 7)
```

Comment: The `StringLength(..., MinimumLength = 8)` attribute that's already in the question *should* suffice to enforce a minimum length, so there shouldn't be a need to explicitly re-check (though it can't hurt, I suppose).

Comment: I try your regex, but it does not work [link](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx). I have validation for length.

Comment: On that link it works fine, it's returning the spaces and periods it matched. If you just type in "Lorem" it will return "Found 0 matches". Look at it on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com) - it highlights the matches on the fly

Comment: @JV regexpal uses JavaScript regexes, not .NET regexes. But as you mention, on cashmere's link, it works too.

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z]` could also be replaced with `[\W0-9]` to not count non-english letters as special

Answer (score 1):

A simple method will be like this:

```
Match match1 = Regex.Match(<input_string>, @"(?=.{7})");
```

match1.Success ensures that there are at least 8 characters.

```
Match match2 = Regex.Match(<input_string>, [^a-zA-Z]);
```

match2.Success ensures that there is at least one special character or number within the string.

```
So, match1.Success && match2.Success guarantees will get what you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried Omega's example however it was not working with my C# code. I recommend using this instead:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=[^\d_].*?\d)\w(\w|[!@#$%]){7,20}", ErrorMessage = @"Error. Password must have one capital, one special character and one numerical character. It can not start with a special character or a digit.")]
```

Answer (score -1):

An expression like this:

```
[a-zA-Z]*[0-9\+\*][a-zA-Z0-9\+\*]*
```

should work just fine (obviously insert any additional special characters you want to allow or use ^ operator to match anything except letters/numbers); no need to use complicated lookarounds. This approach makes sense if you only want to allow a certain subset of special characters that you know are "safe", and disallow all others.

If you want to include all special characters except certain ones which you know are "unsafe", then it makes sense to use something like:

```
\w[^\\]*[^a-zA-Z\\][^\\]*
```

In this case, you are explicitly disallowing backslashes in your password and allowing any combination with at least one non-alphabetic character otherwise.

The expression above will match any string containing letters and at least one number or +,*. As for the "length of 8" requirement, theres really no reason to check that using regex.

Comment: If you list the allowed characters in passwords, you're preventing me from using more secure passwords. You should look at it the other way around (as in J V's answer): if *any* character is *not* a letter, then the password passes the check.

Comment: Word. Edited to reflect this. Also, I think J V's answer is probably better in this situation anyways. I was trying to think of a regex that would match the whole password if valid, but that isn't really necessary. I guess its enough here to just check if any part of the password is not alphabetic, as J V suggested.

Answer (score -1):

```
  function randomPassword(length) {
        var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#$%ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP1234567890";
        var pass = "";
        for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
            var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            pass += chars.charAt(i);
        }
        var pattern = false;
        var passwordpattern = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9+]+[0-9+]+[A-Z+]+[a-z+]");
        pattern = passwordpattern.test(pass);
        if (pattern == true)
            { alert(pass); }
        else
         { randomPassword(length); }
    }
```

try this to create the random password with atleast one special character